# I need help making this regular expression to match part of url

Tags: regex, web-config

I am writing a rewrite rule in web.config file and want to match against a url (using regular expression) if it containes:

```
*/admin*
```

So as long as the url contains above it should match. Example of legal matches:

```
http://test.com/admin
https://test.com/admin
http://test.com/admin/
http://test.com/admin/test
http://test.com/admin/grgr/hht/
```

Example of illegal matches:

```
http://test.com
https://test.com/adminpage
https://test.com/adminpage/
```

I have tried the followings without success:

```
<match url="(.*)/admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
<match url="/admin?" ignoreCase="false" />
<match url=".*/admin?" ignoreCase="false" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

`.*admin(\/.*|$)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
.*\b\/admin\b.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/zq0SAy/1

*Details*:

- `\b` asserts position at a word boundary